# samsung 3401 - cant connect scanner

Tags: printing, samsung, scanner

i downloaded samsung linux driver for my scanner cum printer samsung 3401 and when i click on folder , click on cdroot click on auto run i get this error"

## ! /bin/sh

BASE=`dirname "$0"`
exec sh "$BASE/Linux/install.sh"                                        "

the printer is working , the scanner is not cd provided with the machine is also not working   need help
regards

umesh

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the AutoRun and click "Properties", click "Permissions" then check "Execute: Allow executing file as a program", then double click the autorun file again.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Cgag8fb.png]